# What is the fastest, most standard way to "mass query" a set of grandchildren (has_many, has_many) belonging to a single object?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, has-many-through, has-many

**Use case:** on this site, users will be able to go on and select rental property for a specific amount of days. Users will be often be selling the same type of rental property.

**Problem:** Because multiple "sellers" will be renting out the same exact item, the "property detail page" will *have many* listings created by many different sellers (or in some case, a seller will have multiple properties available falling into the same "property detail page"). Each of these "listings" objects will *have many* pricing objects which contain a date, a price, and an availability boolean.

**Current models are broken down below:**

**property.rb**

```
has_many :listings
has_many :prices, :through => :listings
```

**listing.rb**

```
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :property
has_many :prices
```

**price.rb**

```
belongs_to :listing
```

**What I have tried:**

If for example, I wanted to obtain the MINIMUM sum of pricing for a specific property, I had jotted down this:

```
# property.rb

# minimum price for a pricing set out of all of the price objects
def minimum_price(start_date, end_date)
     # this would sum up each days pricing to give the rental period a final price
     prices = self.prices.where("day <= ?", end_date).where("day >= ?", start_date).sum(:price)
end
```

When I do it like this however, it simply combines every single users prices giving nothing of use.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Of course I could loop through a properties listings until I found a minimum price set for a given date range, but that seems as though it would take an unnecessary amount of time and be largely inefficient.

**EDIT**
An example of data that should be outputted is a set of price objects that are the cheapest ones in a specific date range from ONE particular listing. It can not just combine all of the best priced dates from all of the users and add them as the buyer will be renting from ONE seller.

***This is an actual example of desired output, as you can see these prices are ALL from the same listing ID.***

```
[#<Price id: 156, day: "2020-12-01", listing_id: 7, price: 5.0, available: true, created_at: "2020-12-17 14:22:46", updated_at: "2020-12-17 14:22:46">, #<Price id: 157, day: "2020-12-02", listing_id: 7, price: 5.0, available: true, created_at: "2020-12-17 14:22:46", updated_at: "2020-12-17 14:22:46">, #<Price id: 158, day: "2020-12-03", listing_id: 7, price: 5.0, available: true, created_at: "2020-12-17 14:22:46", updated_at: "2020-12-17 14:22:46">, #<Price id: 159, day: "2020-12-04", listing_id: 7, price: 5.0, available: true, created_at: "2020-12-17 14:22:46", updated_at: "2020-12-17 14:22:46">]
```

Comment: I'm not clear on what you want final data to look like. Maybe give a fake sample of what you want the final result to look like? It sounds like you want some sort of `group by` clause? Also is `minimum_price` a method for `Property`? I seems like it is but you don't specify.

Comment: Updated! Thank you for the request of clarification

Comment: You still aren't showing how you are using the method. I assume you are calling it on `@some_property.minimum_price(...` But can you actually show the use of this method? Show how you are creating the instance variable you are calling it on too please.

Comment: Property.first.minimum_price(Date.today, 4.days.from_now)

Answer (score 0):

So it sounds like you are calling this on a property so:

```
     prices = self.prices.where("prices.day >= ? AND prices.day <= ?", start_date, end_date).sum(:price).group_by {|price| price.listing_id}
```

There is probably a SQL based way that you can use AR relations to do this. But this will give you a hash with a key for each listing_id and the value of that key should be the sum. I say "should" because this is a bit abstract for me to do without a system to test it on.

Comment: Right but that is the primarily difficult part of this question, indicating the listing ID with the use of only a property ID.

```Price.joins(:listing).where("listings.property_id=1").group("prices.listing_id").sum("price")```

How would something like this work given a property ID?

Comment: I'm somewhat confused about what you are asking here. Let me think about it.

Comment: Still not sure my latest answer works. It gets a little confusing since Price has a column of "price". So there is Price.price. If you can successfully sum the prices, you can do a group_by like I show.